# vim: pass a char or word to your function

Tags: vim

I know that when you define a function in vim, you can use the `range` keyword so that users can say:

```
:-5,+5call MyFunction()
```

And then your function gets a:firstline and a:lastline.

What I want is something similar, but more like the traditional vi way of combining a command with a movement, so that 'd ' deletes a space, 'dw' deletes a word, 'd2w' deletes two words, 'd2j' deletes three lines, etc. Assuming my function gets mapped to some input-mode character sequence, is there any way to make it accept similar variable-length inputs, and then modify that text?

Just to be a little more clear, suppose I want to define a function to wrap <b> tags around existing text. We'll say that function is mapped to ;b. I want users to be able to say ';bw' to bold one word, or ';bf.' to bold everything to the end of the sentence, or whatever, with all the flexibility that vim provides to built-in commands.

Comment: You may want to look at [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin. With it enclosing something in a `<b>...</b>` will look like `ys{motion}<b>`. According to the help, you may reduce this to `ys{motion}b` if you execute `let g:surround_{char2nr("b")}="<b>\r</b>"`.

Comment: And, if I am not mistaking, it uses `operatorfunc` option as well, so if you want to define your own function you may find examining surround source code useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, then all you do is include the char argument in your mapping.  For example:

```
map d :call MyFunction('d')<cr>
map dw :call MyFunction('dw')<cr>
map d2w :call MyFunction('d2w')<cr>
" Of course these would be terrible mappings because they 
" are already mapped to important Vim functions
```

The way mappings work is that if you "overspecify" a char like 'd' above so that it is usable either by itself or as a prefix for longer command, Vim will wait briefly (for `timeoutlen`)after you press 'd' to see if you're going to press another character. (This depends on the`timeout` option being set to true, which is the default.) If you don't press another character, Vim will execute the 'd' mapping.  If you do it will call the more complex mapping.  See `:h map-commands` generally and `:h map-typing` for more.

Note:  After your clarification I think what you want is to create a custom 'operator' function that you can use to operate on buffer areas defined by Vim motions.  See `:h map-operator` for info on how to do this.

Comment: This is not really what I mean. I updated the question to be more clear. Basically, I want the 'w' or '2w' part to be any valid movement, so I can't predefine all those commands.

Comment: @Paul -- You may find what you want in `:h map-operator`.  Basically you can define a custom function to which you can feed 'motion' key combinations, like '2w'.

Comment: @ZyX -- I've never used it either.  It's one of those things you remember reading about once somewhere in the maze of Vim documentation, then are sometimes never able to find again. . .

Comment: It looks like `:help map-operator` addresses what I want. Also `:help opfunc` and `:help g@` and `:help mark`. This is complicated! But basically I set `opfunc` to the function I want, use `g@`, and then inside the function use the `'[` and `']` marks to get at the "selected" text. Thanks!